# »Diametral entgegengesetzt« – korrektes Deutsch oder Tautologie?

Tags: phrase, usage

Um Ansichten, Meinungen oder Positionen zu beschreiben, die einander unversöhnlich gegenüberstehen, wird manchmal die Wortgruppe **diametral entgegengesetzt** gebraucht. Das war für mich ganz normaler Sprachgebrauch, bis ich vor kurzem gesagt bekommen habe, das sei eine [Tautologie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautologie_(Sprache)).

Ist das so? *[Diametral](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diametral)* im mathematischen Sinne bedeutet zwar bereits *entgegengesetzt*, aber der Gebrauch von *diametral* alleine fühlt sich für mich, zumindest außerhalb mathematischer Publikationen, sehr seltsam an.

Comment: Also ich kenne die Redewendung nur in der Verwendung, wenn sich beispielsweise "Verhalten und Moral diametral **entgegensteht**". Womit sich die Frage für Mich erübrigt hätte;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ich hab es mir mal einfach gemacht und bei [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/diametral) nachgeschlagen.

Dort wird zwar behauptet, es sei ein Adjektiv (was die Adverb-These stürzen würde), aber da steht auch:

> **Bedeutungen und Beispiele**
>
> ...
>
> 2.) entgegengesetzt, gegensätzlich
>
> ...
>
> *Beispiele*
>
> - diametrale Ansichten
> - **diametral (ganz und gar) entgegengesetzt sein**

Außerdem sollte man bedenken, dass eine Tautologie (z.B. auch "ganz und gar") ein [rhetorisches Stilmittel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautologie_%28Sprache%29) sein kann.

Sicher richtig ist aber, dass man sich der Wirkung einer solchen bewusst sein und sie dann auch nur entsprechend einsetzen sollte. :)

Comment: Danke für Deine Antwort! Guter Punkt, unter dem Aspekt eines rhetorischen Stilmittels hatte ich das noch gar nicht betrachtet...

Answer (score 11):

Selbstverständlich ist die Phrase zulässig.

Und natürlich handelt es sich nicht grundsätzlich um eine Tautologie, sondern um eine präzise Aussage, die bedeutet, dass sich zwei Punkte auf dem Kreis gegenüberliegen.

‚Die Punkte P und Q sind entgegengesetzt‘ oder ‚Die Punkte P und Q sind diametral‘ beinhalten diese Information nicht.

Es gibt natürlich keinen Grund, ausgerechnet diese Metapher zu wählen, um etwa Charaktere zu beschreiben, aber eine Tautologie ist das nicht.

Wenn ich sage: ‚Dieser Vergleich hinkt auf dem linken Bein‘, dann ist die unnötige Präzisierung befremdlich (wenn ich damit nicht eine politische Anspielung ausdrücken will), aber Tautologie ist es keine.

Selbstverständlich sind aber auch Tautologien in Phrasen zur unterstreichenden Betonung erlaubt.

Anscheinend wird „diametral“ im Deutschen praktisch nur als Adverb verwendet, ergänzt also ein Adjektiv. Der Gebrauch ist aber möglicherweise gerade in Veränderung.

Comment: Danke für Deine Antwort! Mein Gesprächspartner war allerdings der Meinung, "diametral" würde den gleichen Informationsgehalt haben wie "diametral entgegengesetzt", und die [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diametral) unterstützt diese These. Dass es bei der alleinigen Verwendung von "entgegengesetzt" weniger klar ist, sehe ich allerdings genauso.

Comment: @Jan Ich glaube, der Punkt ist, dass "diametral" im Deutschen ein Adverb ist und deswegen ein ergänzendes Adjektiv benötigt.

Comment: Das würde allerdings einiges erklären - auch wenn sich die Netzwelt nicht wirklich einig ist, ob wir es hier mit einem Adjektiv oder einem Adverb zu tun haben. [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/diametral), [Canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/Controller?service=canooNet&lookup=caseSensitive&input=diametral) und die [Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-bin/wort_www.exe?site=1&Wort=diametral) sagen Adjektiv, [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=diametral) spricht dagegen von einem Adverb.

Comment: Man könnte auch argumentieren, *diametral* beschreibe zwei Punkte auf einem Kreis, die die maximal mögliche Entfernung voneinander haben. Diese Eigenschaft wird allein durch *entgegengesetzt* nicht abgedeckt.

Comment: @Deve: genau das meinte ich mit meinem ersten Kommentar: "diametral" alleine beschreibt das Gleiche wie "diametral entgegengesetzt", aber "entgegengesetzt" alleine tut es nicht :-)

Answer (score 4):

Die Frage

> Ist das korrektes Deutsch oder eine Tautologie?

macht nur einen Sinn, wenn man annimmt, eine Tautologie wäre fehlerhaftes Deutsch (also ein Deutsch, das nicht korrekt ist). Das ist aber nicht der Fall.

Eine Tautologie ist eine völlig korrekte rhetorische Figur, die häufig zu finden ist, und bei der zwei Synonyme verwendet werden, wo eines eigentlich auch ausreichen würde, z.B.:

> Er wird **nie und nimmer** rechtzeitig am Ziel sein.
>   Ich bin **voll und ganz** deiner Meinung.

Diese Sätze sind also Beispiele sowohl für völlig korrektes Deutsch, als auch für Sätze, die Tautologien enthalten.

Eng mit den Tautologien verwandt sind die Pleonasmen. Bei einem Pleonasmus sind die beiden verwendeten Begriffe keine Synonyme im eigentlichen Sinn, aber eines davon ist ein Adjektiv, das eine Eigenschaft des anderen Begriffs ausdrückt, die im anderen Begriff ohnehin schon implizit enthalten ist.

Beispiele für Pleonasmen:

> Der **kleine Zwerg** hat einen Bart. (*klein* beschreibt eine Eigenschaft von *Zwerg*, aber Zwerge sind ohnehin immer klein)
>   Der Wanderer betrat die Hütte des **alten Greises**. (Ein Greis ist per Definition alt, ihn explizit als alt zu bezeichne stellt einen Pleonasmus dar.)

Im Fall von »*diametral gegenüber*« ist *diametral* eine Adjektiv, das *gegenüber* näher beschreibt, obwohl mit *gegenüber* ohnehin das gemeint ist, was landläufig unter *diametral* verstanden wird.

Und so ist auch dieser Satz ein völlig korrekter deutscher Satz, der eine Abart einer Tautologie (nämlich einen Pleonasmus) enthält:

> Die beiden Saaleingänge liegen genau **diametral gegenüber**.

Strittig ist, ob Tautologien und Pleonasmen stilistisch hoch- oder niederwertige Figuren sind, die Frage nach der Qualität des Stil wurde aber nicht gestellt. Korrektes Deutsch sind diese Figuren allemal.

Answer (score 3):

Wie können zwei Punkte liegen, die diametral sind, aber nicht entgegengesetzt?

Einer am Rand und der andere im Zentrum (Abb. A u. Z)? Das erscheint möglich und mit dem Wort "Diameter" vereinbar, aber nicht gemeint.

Wenn ich mir eine dicke Scheibe vorstelle, dann können zwei Punkte entgegengesetzt sein, bei dem einer oben auf dem Rand sitzt (Abb. A) und der andere entgegengesetzt unten (B2), die also nicht diametral entgegengesetzt (B1) sind.

[image: diametral und entgegengesetzt]

In der nichtgeometrischen, übertragenen Sprechweise scheint es also eher tautologisch zu sein. Was fügt das "diametral" dem Wort "entgegengesetzt" weiter zu?

Aber wenn man als Ort entgegengesetzter Meinungen das Parlament hernimmt, und dessen Anordnung der Parteien als halbkreisähnlich, dann sind die diametral entgegengesetzten Positionen die der äußersten Rechten und die der äußersten Linken.

Ich kann mich für diese Interpretation nicht verbürgen; sie ist durch keinerlei Recherche gestützt. Lediglich das Allgemeinwissen über die Herkunft der Rechts-links-Metaphorik und die oft gesehene Anordnung im Parlament ließen sich auf Verlangen belegen. Würde man im englischen Parlament nicht im Viereck sitzen, so würde ich die Argumentation für schlagend plausibel erklären. So fehlt mir die letzte Sicherheit.

Answer (score 2):

Ob man den Ausdruck als eine Tautologie empfindet oder nicht, hängt sicher davon ab, wie man *entgegengesetzt* definiert. Darüber hinaus ist es eine Frage, ob der Ausdruck empfehlenswert ist, und mir scheint, dass das nicht der Fall ist. Wenn man sich einfacher ausdrücken kann, wirkt eine geschwollene Ausdrucksweise wie *diametral entgegengesetzt* prätentiös und angeberisch.